# How to find Oracle table column collate/Collation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to find Oracle column collation. How to find it. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: Did you make a research on documentation? What did you find?

Answer (score 1):

Collation is available from oracle 12.2. You can use the `user_tab_columns` view as follows:

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_id,
       column_name,
       collation
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Comment: column collation is not available in user_tab_columns/dba_tab_columns/all_tab_columns

Comment: It is availablr but in oracle version 12.2 and above. See this:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=618b6277112d1965d339ddd925520435

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 10, 11 and **12.1** there is no column collation but only parameters `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT`:

```
SQL> show parameter nls_sort

NAME                     TYPE         VALUE
------------------------------------ -------------------- ------------------------------
nls_sort                 string       BINARY
SQL> show parameter nls_comp

NAME                     TYPE         VALUE
------------------------------------ -------------------- ------------------------------
nls_comp                 string       BINARY
```

As of Oracle **12.2** you have [data-bound collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C) and you can retrieve column collation in `DBA_TAB_COLS.COLLATION`.

Comment: I am using Oracle 12.1 and previously I got solution from google but now i am not getting.. Actually it is possible in Oracle 12.1

Comment: In Oracle 12.1 there is no collation that you can define at column level or table level: so it is not possible. For more details see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005.

Comment: Sorry. I am using Oracle 12c... How collation will find in 12c

Comment: I have updated my answer: you need to use `NLS_SORT` and  `NLS_COMP`. See detailed examples in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG293. Note that 12c is not a version number: but 12.1.0.2 and 12.2.0.1 are version numbers: please avoid to use 12c as "version": it makes things only more difficult especially in this case.